# Javascript: Why is Math.floor(1.9) considered as 1 but Math.floor(1.9999999999999999) as 2?

Tags: javascript

Why is  Math.floor(1.9) considered as 1 but Math.floor(1.9999999999999999) as 2?

```
console.log(Math.floor(1.9));// result ==> 1;
console.log(Math.floor(1.9999999999999999));// result ==> 2
```

Comment: Try this: `console.log(1.9999999999999999)` and see what you get.

Comment: @Jesper I get 2

Comment: Indeed. Because `1.9999999999999999` is equal to `2`. Floating-point numbers are not infinitely precise, and JavaScript interprets `1.9999999999999999` as equal to `2`. So when you do `Math.floor(1.9999999999999999)` it is the same as `Math.floor(2)` which is `2`.